# What happens between setVisible() and a component being painted?

Tags: java, swing, visibility

I have a [JScrollPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JScrollPane.html) that contains a [JPanel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JPanel.html) which then contains some custom components which are an extension of JPanel (they are all the same type). This JScrollPane is set invisible before the containing [JFrame](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html) is shown.

When the user selects a [JCheckBox](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JCheckBox.html) I use [`setVisible()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setVisible%28boolean%29) to show the scroll pane. The first time the pane is shown however there is a significant delay between when `setVisible()` is called and when the pane is painted. If the user un-selects and re-selects the check box the pane is painted instantly.

My custom components have already been constructed and added to the panel. They are [ComponentListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/ComponentListener.html)s but have empty implementations except for [`componentResized()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/ComponentListener.html#componentResized%28java.awt.event.ComponentEvent%29). They also have a custom [`paintComponent()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#paintComponent%28java.awt.Graphics%29) method, but a breakpoint inside that method shows the delay happens before the this is called so it is not a case of a slow painting.

Neither the JScrollPane or the JPanel have any other listeners. What else happens between `setVisible()` and `paintComponent()`? Where else could I look to determine the source of the delay?

---

**EDIT:**
In an attempt to create and [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) at the suggestion of [Kevin Workman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/873165/) I discovered my issue is slightly different than I thought. It seems that without anything else happening the scroll pane will never be drawn.

In my minimal example (see below) the item will not be shown until I resize my frame. After the initial display though `setVisible()` applies immediately as in the full program. Here is the example code that demonstrates the problem:

```
public class VisibilityDelayExample extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JCheckBox chckbxAdvancedView;
    private JScrollPane scrollPane;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                    VisibilityDelayExample frame = new VisibilityDelayExample();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public VisibilityDelayExample() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
        setContentPane(contentPane);

        chckbxAdvancedView = new JCheckBox("Advanced View");
        chckbxAdvancedView.addPropertyChangeListener(new PropertyChangeListener() {
            public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent arg0) {
                System.err.println("Property Changed");
                if(chckbxAdvancedView.isSelected() != scrollPane.isVisible()){
                    scrollPane.setVisible(chckbxAdvancedView.isSelected());
                    scrollPane.invalidate();
                    scrollPane.repaint();
                    VisibilityDelayExample.this.invalidate();
                    VisibilityDelayExample.this.repaint();
                }
            }
        });
        contentPane.add(chckbxAdvancedView, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
        scrollPane.setVisible(false);
        contentPane.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        scrollPane.setViewportView(panel);
        for(int j = 0; j < 100;j++){
            panel.add(new JLabel("Label " + j));
        }
    }

}
```

Now the question is, what is happening during a resize that is causing `setVisible()` to take effect and how can I cause it to happen instantly?

Comment: Why don't you look through the source code?

Comment: @KevinWorkman I did trace setVisible() but it seems it only sets some flags in JComponent that I assume are checked in some draw thread, but I don't know where to look to start tracing that process. Other than paintComponent which isn't being called yet.

Comment: It does more than set some flags. JComponent.setVisible() calls Component.setVisible(), which calls Component.show(), which does a bunch of stuff (in fact too much to paste into a comment!). It would be easier to help you with an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrated the behavior though.

Comment: @KevinWorkman Ha I'm so used to not paying attention to super.whateverMethod() in my code that I overlooked it in the setVisible() source. I also added an MCVE which shines a new light on the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Now the question is, what is happening during a resize that is causing

When you resize the frame the layout manager is being called so the size of the scrollpane is changed from (0, 0) to an appropriate value.

> how can I cause it to happen instantly?

When you add/remove components from a visible GUI you need to use `revalidate()` and `repaint()` on the parent container. I know you are not adding the component, but the effect is the same since it doesn't have a valid size.

```
// scrollPane.revalidate();
// scrollPane.repaint();
// VisibilityDelayExample.this.invalidate();
// VisibilityDelayExample.this.repaint();
contentPane.revalidate();
contentPane.repaint();
```

Comment: I erroneously thought that the size of the item would be changed even if it was invisible. I find the `repaint()` to not be necessary as `revalidate()` seems to trigger a repaint.

Comment: @Fr33dan, yes many times you only need a revalidate(). However there can be times when you need both so I generally use both. For example, if you remove a component from a panel and then add another component of the same size, the revalidate() doesn't think anything has changed so the repaint() doesn't automatically get done. If you look at the source code for all the "setter" methods of Swing components they also invoke revalidate() and repaint() automatically.

Comment: Hmm I always tried to get away with as little as possible but if the Swing commands always use both I might rethink that policy.

Answer (score 2):

[Conversely](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22390066/230513), this variation of your example overrides the scrollpane's `getPreferredSize()` method to provide an arbitrary size. The checkbox uses an `ItemListener` to toggle visibility. Note the use of [`pack()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#pack%28%29), which "Causes this `Window` to be sized to fit the preferred size and layouts of its subcomponents."

Addendum: This update makes the scroll pane initially invisible and sizes the frame to accommodate.

[image]

```
public class VisibilityDelayExample extends JFrame {

    private JCheckBox chckbxAdvancedView;
    private JScrollPane scrollPane;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                VisibilityDelayExample frame = new VisibilityDelayExample();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public VisibilityDelayExample() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
        chckbxAdvancedView = new JCheckBox("Advanced View");
        chckbxAdvancedView.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {

            @Override
            public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
                System.out.println(e);
                scrollPane.setVisible(chckbxAdvancedView.isSelected());
            }
        });
        add(chckbxAdvancedView, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1));
        for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++) {
            panel.add(new JLabel("Label " + j));
        }
        scrollPane = new JScrollPane(panel) {

            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                return new Dimension(450, 300);
            }
        };
        add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        pack();
        scrollPane.setVisible(false);
        setSize(scrollPane.getPreferredSize());
    }
}
```

Comment: This example misses one of my requirements that the panel be invisible initially.

Comment: Oh I now I see, if I set my visibility after `pack()` the item has already been sized when I go to show it again later. This makes sense.